# jQuery regex allow only one match replace

Tags: jquery, regex

```
var test = "100pxpxpxpx"; 
test.replace(/[^0-9|px]$/g, '')
```

My desired output is: "100px", but i'm getting the following, how to achieve that?

```
"100pxpxpxpx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just capture the numbers with the single px - ignoring the extras

```
var test = "100pxpxpxpx"; 
test.replace(/^([0-9]+px).*$/g, '$1');
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wb6a0cy1/)

```
^([0-9]+px).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/t2oCduESNL_uv8W7)

Answer (score 1):

Replace multiple occurrences of `px` with an single `px`, using `(px)+`

```
var test = "100pxpxpxpx"; 
test.replace(/[^0-9]+(px)+$/g, 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[^0-9|px]$` regex matches 1 character at the very end of the string that is not a digit, not a `|`, `p` and `x`.

I'd suggest matching rather than replacing:

```js
var test = "100pxpxpxpx"; 
document.body.innerHTML = test.match(/^[0-9]+px/);
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL8vU9/1)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `px` - literal `px` substring.

If you need to replace:

```
(px)[^0-9]+$
```

And replace with `$1`.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL8vU9/3)

```js
var test = "100pxpxpxpx"; 
document.body.innerHTML = test.replace(/px[^0-9]+$/, 'px');
```

Comment: You mean `test = test.match(/^[0-9]+px/);`, right?!

Comment: i need replace. not match

Comment: Well, I think that is all considering current requirements.